# One Iterator Different Types of LinkedList

Tags: java, iterator, listiterator

I am still learning about Iterators and they are so much fun. However I have a question:

I made two `DoubleLinkedList` each with a different generic `<Type>`. I want to iterate through each one using only one `Iterator`, how can I change the generic `<>` on my `Iterator`?

```
DLL<String> aList = new DLL<>();
DLL<Integer> bList = new DLL<>();
DLL<String>.MyIterator<String> it = aList.Iterator();
```

With "`it`" iterator I can only iterate through aList but not bList.

```
it = new bList.Iterator();
```

This code doesn't help because it still thinks it's working with Strings.

Comment: If you want to iterate two lists, you need two iterators. If you want to iterate the second list after the first list, you need to assign the second iterator to a different variable, as it's typed differently.

Comment: So there is no way to use one iterator, iterate through the first list and when i am done I'll make make it iterate through the second list?

Comment: There are concepts like iterator chaining, but basically, you still need to create one iterator per iterated list. That's what the `iterator()` method usually does.

Comment: Alright great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with your `DLL` or `DoubleLinkedList` class, but I think this is not important and confuses the issue. This is my answer using a simple `java.util.List`.

If you really must use the same `Iterator` variable, use the generic wildcard `<?>`. However, be aware that you will have to cast your object, just like in pre-generics Java:

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
Iterator<?> it = stringList.iterator();
String string = (String) it.next();
it = intList.iterator();
Integer integer = (Integer) it.next();
```